# Eclipse - Why does Azure deployment take so long

Tags: deployment, azure

I'm trying to deploy my HelloWorld application in Windows Azure which was developed in Java using eclipse. The application working fine when I tested under tomcat and Azure sdk. I created hosted service in Window Azure Management Portal and deploy my application. It almost 3 hours and it still deploying.

I went to [What Happens When You Deploy on Windows Azure?](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/what-happens-when-you-deploy-on-windows-azure) and checked but still unclear.Can anyone advice why it took so long to deploy and any suggestion how to make the deployment process more faster.

Please refer the image below.
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the startup.cmd, instead of copy my tomcat to azure i changed the startup.cmd to download the tomcat online. now its working fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I wondered the exact same thing just now

Answer (score 0):

Does you start-up script finish after tomcat start?

The instances will be marked as ready only after the start-up script finished, so if you start tomcat blocking the start-up script it won't reach this state unless tomcat crashes...

You should use "start" (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command to start tomcat in a separated process allowing the start-up script to finish.

(In my memories the provided example in the eclipse plugin had the issue)